# Two questions on norms on Banach space products

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, normed-spaces

If $W$ is a Banach space, then is it true that, whatever  the norm we choose on the product space $W\times W$, there exists a constant $C$ with the following property: for all $x, y, x^{\prime}, y^{\prime} \in W,\left|(x, y)-\left(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}\right)\right| \leq$ $C\left(\left|x-x^{\prime}\right|+\left|y-y^{\prime}\right|\right)$?

I have seen this come up in a proof in “Differential Equations Driven by Rough Paths, Terry Lyons et al., 2007’’. I am copying and pasting the proof with the relevant bit highlighted. I am not too sure if, instead of assuming the existence of a constant, they are imposing a norm such that the constant exists, hence it would be interesting to know also: would the proof still be correct, without adding to the statement that the norm of choice should satisfy this bound?

Any help at all would be appreciated.

EDIT: I think the property that I need is that the inclusion map is an isometry, as outlined in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357135/cartesian-product-of-banach-spaces-all-norms-such-that-the-inclusion-is-an-isom) question, in which case my second question is still valid: whether or not this proof without further hypotheses is correct.

*We can now prove a regularity result for the mapping $Y \mapsto f(Y)$. Let $W$ and $U$ be two Banach spaces.*

*Proposition 1.27. Assume that $f: W \longrightarrow U$ is $\operatorname{Lip}(1+\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in$ $(0,1]$. Let $p \geq 1$ be fixed. For every $K>0$, there exists $C_{\alpha, K}>0$ such that, whenever $X$ and $Y$ are two paths of $\mathcal{V}^p(J, W)$ such that $\|X\|_{\mathcal{V}^p} \leq K$ and $\|Y\|_{\mathcal{V}^p} \leq K$, one has
$$
\|f(X)-f(Y)\|_{\mathcal{V}^{\frac{p}{\alpha}}} \leq C_{\alpha, K}\|f\|_{\operatorname{Lip}(1+\alpha)}\|X-Y\|_{\mathcal{V}^p}
$$
Proof. Let $g: W \times W \longrightarrow \mathbf{L}(W, U)$ be a $\operatorname{Lip}(\alpha)$ function such that, for all $x, y \in W, f(x)-f(y)=g(x, y)(x-y)$. Pick $s, t \in J$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left|\left(f\left(X_t\right)-f\left(Y_t\right)\right)-\left(f\left(X_s\right)-f\left(Y_s\right)\right)\right|^{\frac{p}{\alpha}} \\
&\quad=\left|g\left(X_t, Y_t\right)\left(X_t-Y_t\right)-g\left(X_s, Y_s\right)\left(X_s-Y_s\right)\right|^{\frac{p}{\alpha}} \\
&\quad=\left|g\left(X_t, Y_t\right)\left(\left(X_t-Y_t\right)-\left(X_s-Y_s\right)\right)+\left(g\left(X_t, Y_t\right)-g\left(X_s, Y_s\right)\right)\left(X_s-Y_s\right)\right|^{\frac{p}{\alpha}} \\
&\quad \leq 2^{\frac{p}{\alpha}-1}\left|g\left(X_t, Y_t\right)\right|^{\frac{p}{\alpha}}\left|\left(X_t-Y_t\right)-\left(X_s-Y_s\right)\right|^{\frac{p}{\alpha}}+ \\
&\quad+2^{\frac{p}{\alpha}-1}\|g\|_{\operatorname{Lip}(\alpha)}^{\frac{p}{\alpha}}\left|\left(X_t, Y_t\right)-\left(X_s, Y_s\right)\right|^p\left|X_s-Y_s\right|^{\frac{p}{\alpha}} .
\end{aligned}
$$
**Let $C$ be a constant such that, for all $x, y, x^{\prime}, y^{\prime} \in W,\left|(x, y)-\left(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}\right)\right| \leq$ $C\left(\left|x-x^{\prime}\right|+\left|y-y^{\prime}\right|\right)$.** Then from the inequality above, we deduce the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|f(X)-f(Y)\|_{\frac{p}{\alpha}, J}^{\frac{p}{\alpha}} \leq & 2^{\frac{p}{\alpha}-1} \sup _{t \in J}\left|g\left(X_t, Y_t\right)\right|^{\frac{p}{\alpha}}\|X-Y\|_{\frac{p}{\alpha}, J}^{\frac{p}{\alpha}} \\
&+2^{\frac{p}{\alpha}-1}\|g\|_{\operatorname{Lip}(\alpha)}^{\frac{p}{\alpha}} C^p 2^{p-1}\left(\|X\|_{p, J}^p+\|Y\|_{p, J}^p\right)\|X-Y\|_{\infty, J}^{\frac{p}{\alpha}}
\end{aligned}
$$
The result follows easily.*

Comment: The norm should coincide with original norm on $W\times\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times W.$ Usually we take any norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and define $$\|(x,y)\|_{W\times W}=\|(\|x\|_W,\|y\|_W)\|$$

Comment: Logic led us down the same path, as I have just asked a separate but related question linked below. When you say “should”, should that be true for this proof, or that “should” be true in general in order for the norm on the product to be well-defined? 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525275/another-question-on-norms-of-products-of-banach-spaces

I understand what we usually do, and that things work in particular if in your procedure we choose the $L^1$ norm on $\mathbb R^2$. But my question is about the truthfulness of these statements when the norm is *arbitrary*.

Comment: Concerning $\|(x,0)\|_{W\times W}=\|x\|_W$ and $\|(0,y)\|_{W\times W}=\|y\|_W$ it is not necessary, but natural. When you start with $W$ and want to define some  norm on $W\times W$ you expect that the norm is an extension of the norm on each factor of the product. The necessary condition should be $\|(x,0)\|_{W\times W}\sim \|x\|_W$ and  $\|(0,y)\|_{W\times W}\sim \|y\|_W.$ When this condition is satisfied then all such norms are equivalent, provided the space $W\times W$ is complete with the norm $\|\cdot \|_{W\times W}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, thanks. I have been trying to prove that the equivalence requirement $\|(x,0)\| \sim \|x\|$ for both $x$ and $y$ gives equivalence of the product space norm $ \|(\cdot,\cdot)\|$ with the $L^1$-like norm $ \|(\cdot,\cdot)\|’_{W\times W}:= \|\cdot\| _W+\|\cdot\| _W$, but I think this is false in the “lower-bound” direction (see the question I linked in the edit).

Comment: In my previous comment I have assumed that $W\times W$ is complete with respect to $\|\cdot \|_{W\times W}.$ Then all is fine.

Comment: How do you show $\exists C:\forall x,y \in W, C(\|(x,0)\| + \| (0,y)\| )\leq $$ \|(x,y)\| $? Assuming that the norm satisfies “the equivalence condition on the marginals’’ that you require.

Comment: I’ve seen the other question in my edit in detail. What you need to assume is $(x,y) \sim (x,-y)$, and then completeness follows. It made no sense to me that you should “require completeness a priori”, how should I even use completeness to prove equivalence? In fact with the additional assumption above it seems that the equivalence with the L1-like norm is progven, and completeness is deduced a posteriori. Correct if I’m wrong but then it is not at all clear that your completeness assumption will get you equivalence with the L1-like norm

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be a Banach space. Assume the space $W\times W$ is complete with respect to  a norm $\|(\cdot,\cdot)\|.$ Assume also that $$\|(x,0)\|\le c\|x\|,\quad \|(0,y)\|\le c\|y\|$$ The space $W\times W$ is complete with the norm
$$\|(x,y)\|_1=\|x\|+\|y\|.$$ Moreover
$$\|(x,y)\|\le \|(x,0)\|+\|(0,y)\|\le c(\|x\|+\|y\|)=c\|(x,y)\|_1\quad (*)$$
As the spaces $(W\times W,\|(\cdot,\cdot)\|)$ and $(W\times W,\|(\cdot,\cdot)\|_1)$ are complete condition $(*)$ implies that  the norms are equivalent. Hence
$$\|(x,y)\|\ge d\|(x,y)\|_1=d(\|x\|+\|y\|)\ge {d\over c}(\|(x,0)\|+\|(0,y)\|)$$

**Remark** The completeness of $W\times W$ is essential. For example given an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space. There exist two infinite dimensional subspaces $M$ and $N$ such that $M\cap N=\{0\}$ and $M+N$ is not closed. We can identify $M$ and $N$ as infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces, and $M+N$ with the cartesian product of $M\times N.$ The space $M+N$ is not complete.

Comment: Thanks, Ryszard. You write “As the spaces (…) are complete the norms are equivalent”. How do you know this?

Comment: I see you made an edit, but I still don’t understand your first inequality in the last chain of inequalities, where you introduced $d$.

Comment: There is a general fact. If $X$ is a Banach space with respect to norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$  and $$\|x\|_2\le c\|x\|_1$$ then the norms are equivalent. This follows from the inverse mapping theorem. The identity map $I: (X,\|\cdot \|_1)\to (X,\|\cdot \|_2)$ is bounded. Hence the inverse map is bounded. That means $\|x\|_1\le d\|x\|_2$ for some constant $d.$

Comment: You might want to add that $(W×W,∥(⋅,⋅)∥)$ and $(W×W,∥(⋅,⋅)∥_1)$ are not only equal point-wise but also in topology, that the identity as map between them is an homeomorphism.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I would say that as topological spaces they are identical. As normed spaces they are isomorphic.

Comment: That is if you take as granted that the procuct space always has the product topology, which of course is a quite natural assumption.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I ignore that we deal with the space which is the product $X=W\times W.$ The essential is that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ and $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc can you please explain (a) why those two subspaces $M$ and $N$ must exist and (b) why $M\oplus N$ must be incomplete? And can you please finish off your argument, so $M\oplus N$ is never complete but the inclusion map is not bounded (i.e. $\not\exists C: \forall x, |(0,x)|\leq C|x|$) for certain possible choices of norm?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thanks for your help so far, and sorry for the extended questions

Comment: I will just mention the example and left the details for you. Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ be an orthonormal basis in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}.$ Let $M$ be the closed linear span of $\{e_{2n}\}$ and $N$ of $\{f_n\}$ where $f_n= [1-n^{-1/2}]e_{2n}+n^{-1/2}e_{2n-1}.$ Then $M\cap N=\{0\}$ and $M+N$ is a dense subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ as it contains all $e_n.$ But $M+N$ is not closed, therefore not complete. If it was complete then $\mathcal{H}=M+N$ and the norms $\|m+n\| $ and $\|m\|+\|n\|$ would be equivalent. They ar not equivalent. Just look at the decomposition of $e_{2n-1}.$