# Another question on norms of products of Banach spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I recently asked a question on the existence of a constant of equivalence for norms on products of Banach spaces. I have a similar question now: assume $V,W$ are Banach spaces. Let $V \times W$ be their product, and let the norm on the product be *arbitrary*. Is it true that, we can find a constant $C$ such that, for any element of the form $(0,w)$,

$$\|(0,w)\|_{V\times W}\leq C \|w\|_{W}$$

holds true?

If the answer is no, then can you make any meaningful statement on the relationship between $\|(0,w)\|_{V\times W}$ and $\|w\|_{W}$ without any prior knowledge of the specific choice of norm?

Comment: As in the other question, is that not just the demand that the new norm be well-behaved, that $(v,w)\mapsto \|(v,w)\|_{V\times W}$ be a continuous, that is, bounded semi-linear map $V\times W\to\Bbb R_+$?

Comment: That seems like it

Comment: Yes, David, indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, certainly not. If you set $V = 0$ you are asking: if you take a Banach space $W$, with norm $\| w \|$, and then pick a second unrelated norm $\| w \|'$, does there exist a constant $C$ such that $\| w \|' \le C \| w \|$? And the answer is of course not, because you didn't assume any kind of relationship between the norms.

We can perform truly awful constructions such as the following: take $W = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, with $\| w \|$ the $\ell^2$ norm. Now pick a Hamel basis $e_i$ of $W$ consisting of unit vectors, and consider the modified $\ell^2$ norm $\| w \|'$ where the $e_i$ are orthogonal but their lengths are unbounded. Note that $W$ is not complete with respect to $\| w \|'$ and that $\| w \|'$ is badly discontinuous with respect to the topology generated by $\| w \|$.